# Install express.js on Win8 failed

Tags: node.js, express

I had downloaded the latest node.js Win installer. And found `node -v` works! Now I am trying to install express.

Two methods I've tried:

1. `npm install express -g`
2. download the package.json from website and saved,then typed `npm install-g`

But all two methods did not work. Can any one give me an hint? (I had executed `cmd` as administrator,but it still did not work.)

```
C:\microblog>node -v
v0.10.22

C:\microblog>npm install -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
...
npm ERR! not a package C:\Users\wilsonliu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\pause\0.0.1\
package.tgz
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, lstat 'C:\Users\wilsonliu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\express\node_modules\connect\node_modules\qs\.npmignore'
```

Debug txt:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'express',
1 verbose cli   '-g' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.14
3 info using node@v0.10.22
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose cache add [ 'express', null ]
6 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="express" args=["express",null]
7 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
7 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
7 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
7 verbose parsed url   host: null,
7 verbose parsed url   port: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
7 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
7 verbose parsed url   search: null,
7 verbose parsed url   query: null,
7 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'express',
7 verbose parsed url   path: 'express',
7 verbose parsed url   href: 'express' }
8 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
9 verbose lock express C:\Users\wilsonliu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\f3c62de4-       express.lock
10 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
11 silly lockFile f3c62de4-express express
12 verbose addNamed [ 'express', '' ]
13 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
```

Comment: What happens if you just do `npm install express`?

Comment: Can you delete everything from `C:\Users\wilsonliu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and try?

Comment: You are my hero!!It works!!Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you delete everything from `C:\Users\wilsonliu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` and try?

If you had run npm with or without sudo earlier, the lockfiles create each time may cause such errors.

Besides it's better to avoid using `sudo` when installing node packages.

You can specify location under user's home folder while installing node. Even if you have installed node/npm as administrator, you should consider `chown` the node install dir (mostly `/usr/local/node`) to your local user: `sudo chown <user> /usr/local` and `sudo chown -R <user> /usr/local/*`.